# Как посчитать длину строки без управляющих символов

Tags: python, строки

Как вернуть длину строки не считая управляющие символы?
Например строка будет 'Denis\nShamra\v\t\r'
len строки должeн равняться 11.
Подскажите можно ли тут использовать метод строки какой-то или только можно использовать регулярные выражения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать регулярное выражение по которому все `whitespace` будут удалены

`\s`- это тоже самое, что `[ \f\n\r\t\v]`. Т.е. еще и пробелы будут удалены

Пример:

```
import re

text = 'Denis\nShamra\v\t\r'
new_text = re.sub(r'\s', '', text)
print(len(new_text))
# 11
```

Comment: А мне интересно как избежать удалению пробелов? Вдруг пользователь будет вписывать пробелы? Чтобы нам вернуть строку которую он ввел.

Comment: @Pain. `new_text = re.sub(r'[\f\n\r\t\v]', '', text)`

Answer (score 5):

Можно воспользоваться тем, что все управляющие символы находятся в начале таблицы `Unicode`, поэтому их числовое представление через `ord` не превышает `31`:

```
a = 'Denis\nShamra\v\t\r'

print(len(''.join(x for x in a if ord(x) >= 32)))
```

Вывод:

> `11`

Answer (score 2):

```py
from unicodedata import category

a = 'Denis\nShamra\v\t\r'
print(len(a))
print(len(''.join(filter(lambda x: category(x) != 'Cc', a))))
# 15
# 11
```